# Class not found in Cloud Bigtable SDK

Tags: java, hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I've installed the Google Cloud Bigtable Java SDK and it can not find the following class: `TableName is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.hbase` . I used the version link as described [on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
    <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.0</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TableName` class is a part of HBase, not Cloud Bigtable. For an example, take a look at [Simple-CLI](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/simple-cli).

You'll note that in the `pom.xml`, we have:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
      <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.1</artifactId>
      <version>${bigtable.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where `bigtable.version` = 0.2.2 and `hbase.version` = 1.1.1

Comment: Thanks. I've found the issue, hbase-client has a dependency on hbase-common that does not seem to be resolved by sbt. I'll fill a bug on sbt :)